# How to assign a shortcut to the mouse navigation button in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using VS2010, VS2012 & VS2013.

I want to assign a keyboard shortcut to the back/next navigation buttons to be set to View.NavigateBackward and View.NavigateForward.
In the toold->options->keyboard I can't bind a command shortcut to a mouse-previous nor mouse-next button. Maybe because they are not *keyboard*-shortcuts...

Is there any way to assign a shortcut to those? (or to any mouse+keyboard shortcuts)

I know they are set by default to do almost the same thing but still I find the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> (NavigateBackward and View.NavigateForward respectively) to be much more predictive and so much more usefull.

I saw this post (which also writes how the mouse-previous and mouse-next button work in VS by default):
[How do Visual Studio 2012's navigation buttons behave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926282/how-do-visual-studio-2012s-navigation-buttons-behave/11978897#11978897)

and also the link there on the answer is broken.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible without a VS extension, which can be found here: [Link](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/87fb8c65-d1db-49e9-a068-d62a222a4ae7/). Sometimes though, the navigation backwards does not work with the mouse, but works when pressing the button in the interface.